# Bucky tutorial GUI part 8

Tags: python

I'm easily confused with classes. Why does he use `self` in buttons like `self.printButton` while he didn't use `self` in `frame`?

```
from tkinter import *

class JohnsButton:

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.printButton = Button(frame, text="Print Message", command=self.printMessage)
        self.printButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.quitButton = Button(frame, text="Quit", command=frame.quit)
        self.quitButton.pack(side=LEFT)

    def printMessage(self):
        print("WOW, this actually worked!")


root = Tk()

b = JohnsButton(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `frame` will be forgotten about after the method it is in is finished running; you generally can't access it outside of `__init__`. `self` allows you to "remember" a variable, so something like `self.printButton` will be available in other methods as it is attached to the class instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`frame` will not be "forgotten", but will go out of scope after **init** is done, so you will no longer be able to access it. If there were no references to 'frame', the frame object would also be destroyed, but in this case self.printButton needs it and holds a reference to it, so it will be around until the button is destroyed, yet you will have no way to access it.

Let's say you want to add another button in method `def f(self)', so you need to pass the frame to the Button constructor again. In this case you would need to upgrade it to a member variable:

```
self.frame = Frame(master)
self.frame.pack()
self.printButton = Button(self.frame, text="Print Message")
```

Nothing else will change functionality-wise, except now you can access `frame` via the class JohnsButton object.